# Слово из букв Python

Tags: python, json, for

Как из букв сделать слово.
У меня есть цикл:

```py
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

проблема: Я парсил `json` и теперь этот цикл выводит каждый символ `value` т.е у меня есть `json` в котором я написал:

```json
{
"name1": "images",
"value": "cap.png"
}
```

и

```json
{
"name2": "images",
"value": "pic.png"
}
```

Пытался получить каждый value, пришёл циклу который я написал свыше, он выводит value но по одному символу а мне нужно слово.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для python тип json приводится к типу данных словарь (в терминах python - `dict`). Почитать можно [официальную документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Разберем поэтапно

```py
import json
data_json = '{"name1": "images", "value": "cap.png"}'
data_dict = json.loads(data_json)
```

Переменная `data_json`- это и есть ваши данные. Чтобы превратить в словарь используем метод `loads()`.

Если проверить по типам данных в самом python, то результаты будут такие

```py
>>> type(data_json) 
<class 'str'>
>>> type(data_dict) 
<class 'dict'>
```

И теперь пробежаться по значениям и ключам не так и сложно:

```py
for key, value in data_dict.items():
  print(f"Key is {key} and value is {value}") 
 
Key is name1 and value is images
Key is value and value is cap.png
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое